# deleting 1 month old records from SQLite table

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm developing an android application in which every day i want to check 1 month older records present in table, if i want to delete 1 month older records from table, i m saving insertion time as long value (System.currenttimemillis) in the table its data type is REAL.  Is there any direct query available in sq-lite to delete older records by specifying interval.?

I got below query in MySQL is this works in sq-lite?? please help me...

```
     DELETE FROM [table] WHERE [InsertTime] < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

Comment: since there is no date type in sqlite you should be more specific on how you store date in sqlite database(int? varchar? if varchar then which format?)

Comment: `SQLiteDatabase.deletedelete (table, "InserTime < ?", new String[] { "" + (time_in_millis - one_month_in_millis) });`

Answer (score 3):

A query like this should do the job:

```
DELETE FROM <table> WHERE datetime(<dateColumn> / 1000, 'unixepoch') < datetime('now', '-1 month')
```

The division by `1000` is necessary since you're storing the timestamp in milliseconds, but SQLite understands seconds for `unixepoch`.

Answer (score 0):

This subtracts one month from current date.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
```

Once u have the date perform delete query